# rendering special effects in html5 canvas only when frame rate allows it

Tags: javascript, html, render, game-loop

I setup my game loop as follows:

```
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
        return  window.requestAnimationFrame   ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
            function( callback ){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
    })();
    (function gameLoop() {
        var time                =   new Date().getTime();
        var dt                  =   (time - prevFTime) / 1000.0;
        prevFTime               =   time;

        state.effectsOn         =   dt > 1 / 60.0 ? true : false;
        state.effectsOn         =   false;

        //game rendering logic goes here

        window.requestAnimFrame(gameLoop);
    })();
```

Now what I want to do is if the `effectsOn` variable is set in cause of good frame rate, then I will render some special effects in my game. If not, I will simply skip rendering those special effects.

But my obvious problem is that if `dt>1/60` and effectsOn is set to true. I will be rendering special effects which ll lead to increasing in rendering time, thus possibility of making `dt < 1/60` thus making effectsOn to false.

Is there any good alternative way to achieve what I am trying to do?

In the worst case, I can put up a check box sort of thing in my main menu and let the user decide whether to render special effects or not...

Comment: BTW don't just do on/off if possible. You could i.e. try to set the amount of particles stepwise, like all/most/few/none, depending on the framerate.

Comment: I'd also recommend what 'large' games do- perform the measure on a specially-set screen where there's a lot of effects and set the settings based on that, so that the user would get consistent experience through your game.

Answer (score 2):

Just leave the special effects on initially.

If after the first `n` frames the average rendering time is too high, turn them off, and leave them off.

Comment: Preferably allow the user to turn them back on permanantly as well.